# Ajustar automáticamente la altura de fila de un JTable dependiendo del contenido en Java NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jtable

Hola tengo una tabla con datos de mysql y cuando los muestro en un Jtable quiero que  la altura de fila se adapte al tamaño de texto
Esta es mi tabla
[image: Problema]

Como debe mostrar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora encontré este método pero al llamarlo no me funciona y sigue igual :
leí  que debo envolverlo en un EventQueue.invokeLater() pero no se como hacerlo:

```
private void updateRowHeights() {

    for (int row = 0; row < jTable1.getRowCount(); row++) {

        int rowHeight = jTable1.getRowHeight();

        for (int column = 0; column < jTable1.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            Component comp = jTable1.prepareRenderer(jTable1.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
            rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
        }

        table.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya has probado a usar `FontMetrics`?

Comment: Hola gracias  por responder,  aun no como lo aplicaría?

Comment: obteniendo la altura de la fuente